# running fxcop from sonarcube

Tags: c#, .net, sonarqube, fxcop

I am using SonarQube 5.1.1 and I cannot find a way to run fxcop on it, it shall be working out of the box as I am using C# 4.1 plugin.

I have tried adding multiple params in SonarQube.Analysis.xml (I am using MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.0) with now effect.

I have no info in log regarding fxcop except:

> 9:06:21 AM  09:06:21.410 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpFxCopProvider$CSharpFxCopSensor@2037eb7
>   9:06:21 AM  09:06:21.640 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpFxCopProvider$CSharpFxCopSensor@2037eb7 (done) | time=230ms

P.S. stylecop runs well at the same time.

If you know how to run it please share your SonarQube.Analysis.xml and sonar-project.properties.

Comment: You should not have to add any parameter to the `SonarQube.Analysis.xml` file to get FxCop to work. Could you provide the logs of your `msbuild` build, does it show FxCop running? Can you have a look at the generated `sonar-project.properties` file, does it contain a path to an FxCop report? Does that report contain issues on specific files that are imported into SonarQube? (FxCop issues that do not map to source elements - e.g. because of missing .pdb - are ignored)

Comment: Are you sure the rule profile in question contains FxCop rules? You can double-check by clicking-through on the profile's rule count, then narrowing the rule results by Repository.